# Dormers with ridge vents lower than main ridgeline

Tags: roof, attic, ventilation, dormer

My roof contractor placed ridge vents on all peaks on my home, including the dormers.  So, I have the main attic space, which is vented by a ridge vent running the entire length.  I have plenty of soffit vents as intake; while the dormer have none.  The dormers now have ridge vents on their peaks and they are just shy of the main house's peak, but about a foot or two.  The dormer attic spaces are open to the main space.

I know that it is okay to vent the dormers if they peaks are at the same height, and that if they are lower they could act as intakes.  Is a foot or two difference something to worry about?  Are the dormer ridge vents still going to exhaust air or are they going to now short circuit the system?

Comment: It's difficult to say for sure, but the smaller the difference in ridge heights in proportion to overall heights, the less likely there will be any issues with ridge intake. IMO you will not have any issues from the sound of things.

Comment: I think I'm good.  I have added so much soffit venting, if nothing else, I am hanging my hat on the fact that I have improved the situation drastically.